# For loop is not processing next element if current condition met

Tags: python

I am trying to remove wowels in a random text.

```
def disemvowel(string):
    wowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    wowellist = list(wowels)

    correctedList = list(string)

    for i in correctedList:
        for j in wowellist:
            if i == j:
                j = wowellist[0]
                correctedList.remove(i)
                print(i)


    string = "".join(str(x) for x in correctedList)
    return string

print(disemvowel("Your text wowel will be removed!"))
```

But when removed first wowel "o" second one "u" is not processed. I think it is due to `correctedList.remove(i)` but how can I remove an element in the list another way?

Answer (score 2):

```
def disemvowel(string):
    wowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    wowellist = list(wowels)

    correctedList = list(string)
    outlist=[x for x in correctedList if x not in wowels]
    string = "".join(str(x) for x in outlist)
    return string

print(disemvowel("Your text wowel will be removed!"))
```

Comment: How was this question answered AFTER it was marked duplicate? That has never worked for me.

Comment: I did not see that. I must have started answering it before it was marked duplicate :P

Comment: I've done that before, but the answer button becomes gray and unclickable when it gets marked duplicate.

Comment: Sorry no clue then

Comment: FYI, I have fixed this issue with copying list, see following:

for i in correctedList[:]: